# MySQL: все записи кроме

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать MySQL запрос таким образом, вытащить все кроме одного ,

```
SELECT * FROM `users` КРОМЕ `id`= '$id'
```

Comment: **id != '$id'**

Comment: спасибо, блогадорю

Comment: Плиззз ...

Answer (score 4):

*Ответ из комментария:*

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != '$id'
```

или:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id <> '$id'
```